# How can I set the value inside a field to a table td with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  few fields and I want the values inside those fields to get copied to `tbody td`.
I have made an jsfiddle could someone please take a look at it.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsdUU/

I would like to have each tbody td looks like follow:

> Copied value: (value that was typed inside the fields)

Any kind of help is appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u need to copy the value from input to td or td to input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here is a working version of [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/tsdUU/9/).  Now for the explanation.

Quick!  What is wrong with this code.

```
<select id="SubjectTypeName" id="1">
```

It has two `id`s which prevents us from selecting it by `id`.  Secondly, in your code you are trying to set the value of a textbox (`#1`) to the value of a `td` (`#S`).

```
$("#1").val($("#S").val());
```

So we need to change that code to.

```
$("#S").val($("#1").val());
```

Ah, but this code still won't work.  This is because a cell doesn't have a value attribute, which is what `val()` returns.  Instead we are trying to set the `innerHTML`; which has a jQuery alternative of `html()`.

```
$("#S").html($("#1").val());
```

And, tada!  It works!  =D

**EDIT:** Getting the text of a selected option.

To do this we need to get the selected option.  Which we can do via the `:selected` selector.

```
$("#1 option:selected");
```

Now we just get the inner text of this using the `text()` method.

```
$("#1 option:selected").text();
```

Put it all together and we get.

```
$("#S").html($("#1 option:selected").text());
```

Comment: It's okay.  It's not a competition anyways, right?  **stabs**

Comment: Awesome, is there by any chance possible to copy the text inside the ddl and not the value number?

Answer (score 1):

change the jquery code to

```
$('#next-step').click(function() {
    $('#S').html('Copied value: ('+$("#1").val()+')');
    $('#C').html('Copied value: ('+$("#2").val()+')');
    $('#T').html('Copied value: ('+$("#3").val()+')');
});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

this is your html

```
<input type="text" value="" id ="three" />
<input type="text" value="" id="two" />
<select id="one">
<option value="">Select something</option>
<option value="2">test1</option>
<option value="3">test2</option>
<option value="4">test3</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<table class="box-style3" border="1">
 <thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td id="S">Copied value:</td></tr>
<tr><td id ="C">Copied value:</td></tr>
<tr><td id="T">Copied value:</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="next-step"  value="save">
```

this is your js

```
$('#next-step').click(function() {
$('#S').html($('#one').val());
$('#C').html($('#two').val());
$('#T').html($('#three').val());
});
```

and its working

Answer (score 0):

Most of the guys already gave answers, here's mine though.

Your HTML code:

```
<input type="text" value="" id ="3" />
<input type="text" value="" id="2" />
<select id="1">
<option value="">Select something</option>
<option value="2">test1</option>
<option value="3">test2</option>
<option value="4">test3</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<table class="box-style3" border="1">
  <thead></thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td id="S">Copied value:</td></tr>
    <tr><td id ="C">Copied value:</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="T">Copied value:</td></tr>
     </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="next-step"  value="save">
```

and here's the script

```
$('#next-step').click(function() {
    $('#S').append($('#1 option:selected').text());
    $('#C').append($('#2').val());
    $('#T').append($('#3').val());
});
```

​Simpy remove this id on the select tag, id="SubjectTypeName" and you're good to go.